# SignalR utilizar mi IP

Tags: c#, windows-forms, signalr, aplicación-escritorio

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de consola que actúa como servidor empleando
`Signalr`. La idea es que los usuarios piden información en tiempo real a este servidor.

A la hora de trabajar con `localhost` todo funciona perfectamente ahora estoy intentando levantar el servidor con mi `IP` Codigo;

Servidor

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url =@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/signalr";//sustituir con mi IP
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}", url));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Clase Startup

```
class Startup 
{

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Conexión en el cliente

```
 public void startComunication()
    {

        string url = @"http://localhost:8080/signalr"; //sustituir localhost con la ip correspondiente.
        var connection = new HubConnection(url);
        _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
        connection.Start().Wait();
    }
```

A la hora de cambiar el `localhost` por mi `IP`intento lanzar de nuevo la APP del servidor y me da el siguiente error;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes probar tratar de lanzar el proceso con otro puerto?

Comment: Conoces los web services?, te invito a que lo mires un poco porque es muy sencillo de implementarlo y creo que se ajusta perfectamente a tus necesidades

Comment: @Veelicus si, lo conocía, pero decidí hacerlo en una aplicación de consola, ya que no necesito interfaz gráfica, pero creo que ha sido complicarme la vida.

Comment: Puedes seguir utilizando la aplicacion de consola para conectarte al servicio web, si tienes un par de horas para probar yo lo intentaria, veras que es mucho mas sencillo y escalable

Comment: Solucioné el error, venia dado por no ejecutar el VS como administrador. Y no podía lanzar el servidor con mi `IP`.

Comment: @HectorLopez son cosas distintas, signalr permite comunicación bidireccional y notifcaciones push desde servidor y los clientes.